# How to use like operator in SQL query string? I got 'Incorrect syntax near 'A''

Tags: sql-server

Statement:

```
declare @Searchkey varchar(50)='a'
declare @Sql nvarchar(max) =''

set @Sql = @Sql + 
    'select * from products where upper(ProductName) like %' + upper(@Searchkey) + '%'

execute sp_executesql @Sql
```

Error message:

> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: The like wildcard `%` should be inside the string.

Comment: It would appear you believe that `sp_executesql` protects you from [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683). It does not. It would have if you [used parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813144/11683) when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that you need to add quotes around the search pattern, when you build the dynamic statement. But I think that your should use parameter in this dynamically built statement to prevent SQL injection issues:

```
DECLARE @Searchkey varchar(50) = 'a'
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = N''

SET @Sql = 
    @Sql + 
    N'SELECT * FROM products WHERE UPPER(ProductName) LIKE CONCAT(''%'', UPPER(@Searchkey), ''%'')'

PRINT @Sql
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Searchkey varchar(50)', @Searchkey
```

Answer (score 1):

***You do not require a dynamic query for such case, you can use below simple query to get the desired result.***

```
declare @Searchkey varchar(50)= 'a'
select * from products where upper(ProductName) like  '%' + upper(@Searchkey) + '%'
```

*If you still want to go with Dynamic query then below are the connect syntax.*

```
declare @Searchkey varchar(50)='a'
declare @Sql nvarchar(max) =''

set @Sql =@Sql+'select * from products where upper(ProductName) like ''%' +upper(@Searchkey)+'%'''

--print @Sql
execute sp_executesql @Sql
```

*Note: Whenever you will get an error with a dynamic query then the best way is to print the query using print statement that will help to identify the error easily. In your case, a single quote was missing.*

Answer (score 0):

You're not placing quotes around your search term, so the literal query that's being sent is:

```
select * from products where upper(ProductName) like %A%
```

You need to wrap the search term in quotes, like so:

```
set @Sql =@Sql+'select * from products where upper(ProductName) like ''%'+upper(@Searchkey)+'%'''
```

This will create the following query:

```
select * from products where upper(ProductName) like '%A%'
```